# C# query using a generic Type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make a generic function to do a database call (see code below). I have put the function in a separate solution, so that i can use it in different projects.

the line:

```
var data =  d.Database.SqlQuery<T> (sql).First();
```

gives me the error:

> Invalid object name 'VM_MailData'

(VM_MailData is the type I add as generic type T)

```
public static void ProcessData<T>(string Group, int Id)
{
   string ConnectionString = "SomeConnectionStringName";
   string sql = "select top 1 * from " + (typeof (T).Name) + " where " + Group + "Id = " + Id + ";";             
   DbContext d = new DbContext(ConnectionString);
   var data =  d.Database.SqlQuery<T> (sql).First();
   //Do some stuff with the data...
   html = "some tekst...";
   foreach (var sourceProperty in data.GetType().GetProperties())
   {
    html = html.Replace("{#" + sourceProperty.Name + "#}",    sourceProperty.GetValue(data, new object[] { }) == null ? "" : sourceProperty.GetValue(data, new object[] { }).ToString());
    //enter code here

   }
}
```

Comment: Well, `VM_MailData` does not match `VW maildata`, for one

Comment: Does the table exist in the database? Is the naming convention case sensitive?

Comment: Where does `Group` come from, and do you know about [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/)?

Comment: icepickle The doesnt reach the database, but the sql is correct and the query does return a record. james-thorpe SQL injection is no issue this is only a simle code example the real code deals with all of these problems.

Comment: _"Invalid object name 'VM_MailData'"_ would seem to indicate that that table/view/whatever [doesn't exist in your database](http://imgur.com/N2C6y2z).  Are you sure that your tables/views/whatevers _exactly_ match your type names?

Comment: The `Invalid object name` message looks very much like an error message from SQL server. It might be that your connection string is incorrect. Are you setting `initial catalog = <your DB name>` in the connection string? You just might be querying the wrong DB...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most probably need to call `ProcessData<T>(string Group, int Id)` with some  base type of `VM_MailData`. I assume that VM stands for "view model" and you have something like

```
public class MailData
{
} 

public class VM_MailData : MailData
{
}
```

Where MailData class is actually the one that has a corresponding table.
So instead of calling `ProcessData<VM_MailData >("some group", 1)` you need to call `ProcessData<MailData>("some group", 1)`.

**P.S. You really should use parameterized queries to avoid SQL Injection!**

Answer (score 0):

I can see where you're heading :) so...
You have to create a map (dictionary) that maps from Type to appropriate table name. You can built that using some kind of convention based on the name of the type or the tables.

Use those to get available tables and views in the dabatase

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) as SchemaName, name as Name FROM sys.tables
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) as SchemaName, name as Name FROM sys.views
```

You can use the following script to get the primary key column of the table.

```
DECLARE @origin_table_name AS VARCHAR(50)

SET @origin_table_name = 'Your_table_name_goes_here'

    SELECT
        s.name AS TABLE_SCHEMA
      , t.name AS TABLE_NAME
      , c.name AS COLUMN_NAME
      , k.name AS CONSTRAINT_NAME
      , ic.key_ordinal AS ORDINAL_POSITION
    FROM
        sys.key_constraints AS k
    JOIN sys.tables AS t ON t.object_id = k.parent_object_id
    JOIN sys.schemas AS s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
    JOIN sys.index_columns AS ic ON ic.object_id = t.object_id
                                    AND ic.index_id = k.unique_index_id
    JOIN sys.columns AS c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
                             AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
    WHERE
        k.type = 'PK'
        AND t.name = @origin_table_name
```

Good luck